# How to jump up or down to first non-whitespace character in same column

Tags: evil, search, motion

I use evil-mode with Emacs and would like to accomplish this via evil-mode, but would be fine with doing it in an Emacs-centric way too. The subject line explains it well, but here is a post in which a Vim user posted the same question as mine and received the Vim-centric answer (several actually): [How do I move vertically until reaching a non-whitespace character?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-do-i-move-vertically-until-reaching-a-non-whitespace-character)

Another useful link, similar to that provided above: [Move to the next row which has non-white space character in the same column in VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882722/move-to-the-next-row-which-has-non-white-space-character-in-the-same-column-in-v)

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I decided I'd write a function to do this and it was surprisingly easy:

```
(defun jump-down-to-non-whitespace-char-in-same-column ()
  (interactive)
  (next-line)
  (while (or (= (char-after (point)) 32)
             (= (char-after (point)) 10))
    (next-line)))
```

I guess I'd still like to know if there is a way to do it with evil-mode anyway just because I am curious, so I won't answer my own question yet.

UPDATE 2: I prefer the following version instead as now I use evil-next-line and evil-previous-line which behave more consistently the way I want:

```
(defun jump-down-to-non-whitespace-char-in-same-column ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-next-line)
  (while (or (= (char-after (point)) 32)
            (= (char-after (point)) 10))
    (evil-next-line)))

(defun jump-up-to-non-whitespace-char-in-same-column ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-previous-line)
  (while (or (= (char-after (point)) 32)
            (= (char-after (point)) 10))
    (evil-previous-line)))
```

Then in my evil-leader config I use "c d" `jump-down-to-non-whitespace-char-in-same-column` and "c u" `jump-up-to-non-whitespace-char-in-same-column`

Comment: I suggest moving your own answers to actual answers, and maybe expand a bit on the difference between the first and the "evil" versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following :

```el
(defun next-line-non-empty-column (arg)
  "Find next line, on the same column, skipping those that would
end up leaving point on a space or newline character."
  (interactive "p")
  (let* ((hpos (- (point) (point-at-bol)))
         (re (format "^.\\{%s\\}[^\n ]" hpos)))
    (cond ((> arg 0)
           (forward-char 1) ; don't match current position (can only happen at column 0)
           (re-search-forward re))
          ((< arg 0)
           (forward-char -1)           ; don't match current position.
           (re-search-backward re)
           (goto-char (match-end 0))))
    ;; now point is after the match, let's go back one column.
    (forward-char -1)))
(defun previous-line-non-empty-column (arg)
  ""
  (interactive "p")
  (next-line-non-empty-column (- arg)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-n") 'next-line-non-empty-column)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-p") 'previous-line-non-empty-column)
```

IIRC I went for the regexp way because of performance reasons. Not saying that this is the best implementation, but it was better than my previous one (don't remember what it was).

Comment: Thanks @YoungFrog, appreciate it. Nice to have a regexp solution. I'll try to remember to give some points to you when my rep here grows.

Comment: Please note that this will not match exactly your code (with `next-line`) when `visual-line-mode` is on (and `truncate-lines` is nil) : if you have a very long lines which wraps, your code will stop on the next visual line, whereas this code will not. (I don't know how `evil-next-line` behaves.)

Comment: This is something that never occurred to me but now that I've added it I'm using it a lot -- thanks!